# What is the scope of a 'var' declared inside a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could someone clarify for me please... I've read that creating a variable using reserved word 'var' makes that variable public but how can that be if the variable was created inside a function:

```
$('#timeIn').timepicker({ 'scrollDefaultNow': true });
    $('#timeIn').on('change', function() {
        var numIn = $('#timeIn').timepicker(('getSecondsFromMidnight'));
        var inHours = {
            hours: (numIn/86400)*24,
            getter: function() {return this.hours;}
        };
        timeIn = $('#timeIn').val();
        inArray.push(timeIn);
        events.push(timeIn);
});
```

In this example the variables numIn & inHours are only known within that onChange method, correct? If that is the case what would the global declaration look like? The 'timeIn' is globally scoped but without manipulation I only get a string representation back. What are my options for getting a computable time back as return.

Comment: See [JavaScript Variable Scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)

Comment: @pst you are correct sir but part of I wanted most was a confirmed rebuttal of the reserve word 'var', when and where to use it and what can see it-but there is a ton of information on scope at your link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript uses function scope - every variable can be seen only from within the same function or a scope higher than it.

An implicit global variable is what happens when you use a variable without first declaring it. In compiled languages this would result in a compilation error, but javascript silently declares the variable as a property of the global object (in a browser this is the `window` object)

```
$('#timeIn').on('change', function() {
    var numIn; // only available from inside this anonymous handler function
    ... snip ...
    timeIn = $('#timeIn').val(); // this is an implicit global since it has not been declared anywhere
    // an explicit global, for example's sake
    window.someVar = 'foo';
});
```

With javascript v1.7 you can also establish block scopes via the [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) keyword:

```
let(a = 5, b = 1) {
    // a and b are scoped to this block
    console.log(a+b); // 6
}
console.log(a+b); // error
```

Answer (score 10):

Using the word `var` within the function binds it to that function's scope.

Not using the word `var` makes it public in all functions and all scopes

Comment: Clarification: not using `var`, binds the name to the _global object_, which in browsers is the `window` object, but in other environments (e.g. Node) might be different.

Comment: Also, an interesting minor detail: `var` in "global scope" has the side-effect of making it non-`delete`'able .. (it is resolvable as a property, but treated as a variable)

Comment: @pst you can't say `delete window.someVar;`?

Comment: @jbabey `var x = 2; delete x; window.x` this differs from `y = 2; delete y; window.y` (assuming global scope in both examples) .. it's just a little detail, but `var` in global scope does do something. (My preference/style dictates explicitly using `window.globalProp` and not using `var` in a global context, but that's another story ..)

Answer (score 2):

There are only 3 scopes in JavaScript.

`x = 1;` <- `x` is in global scope

var, when used outside of a function, will also create a global:

`<script type="text/javascript">var x = 1;</script>` <- `x` is in global scope

`function () { var x = 1; }` <- `x` is in function scope

`for (let i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {}` <- `x` is in block scope

Comment: A function body is a block, so it is still block scope.

Comment: @pst, that's the whole context.

Comment: @lanzz No. Because C has "block scope"; e.g. `if (y) {int x; x = 1;}`

Comment: @Mythril My point is that there is not enough context given in this reply :) It is not the assignment that makes it global, it is the *lack* of being scoped otherwise. Including more context in this reply will remove the ambiguity.